# how to ignore random kubernetes pod name in deployment file

Tags: kubernetes

Below is my kubernetes deployment file -

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: boxfusenew
  labels:
    app: boxfusenew
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: boxfusenew
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: sk1997/boxfuse:latest
        name: boxfusenew
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

In this deployment file under container tag **boxfusenew** pod name is specified. So I want the pod generated by deployment file should have the **boxfusenew** name but the deployment is attaching some random value to it as- **boxfusenew-5f6f67fc5-kmb7z**.

Is it possible to ignore random values in pod name through deployment file??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, unless you create the Pod itself and not a deployment.

According to Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/names/):

> Each object in your cluster has a Name that is unique for that type of resource. Every Kubernetes object also has a UID that is unique across your whole cluster.
>
> For example, you can only have one Pod named myapp-1234 within the same namespace, but you can have one Pod and one Deployment that are each named myapp-1234.
>
> For non-unique user-provided attributes, Kubernetes provides labels and annotations.

If you create a Pod with a specific unique label, you can use this label to query the Pod, so no need of having the exact name.

You can use a jsonpath to query the values that you want from your Pod under that specific deployment. I've created an example that may give you an idea:

`kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.metadata.labels.app=="boxfusenew")].metadata.name}'`

This would return the name of the Pod which contains the label `app=boxfusenew`. You can take a look into some other examples of jsonpath [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#viewing-finding-resources) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/).

Answer (score 1):

First what kind of use case that you want to achieve? If you want to simply get available pods belongs to certain deployment you can use [label](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/) and selector. For example:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> get po -l <key>=<value>
```